# How to sort String values which comprises Null values, Long integer values like 100000001, alphanumeric values like vdlv12300?(java)

Tags: sorting

I require them sorted in ascending order as integer values first and then alphanumeric values and then null values. I tried using comparator in java which compares the String. But the results are distorted. Then, I seperated null values and actual values. I placed this actual values in to a tree map and then retrieved to get in ascending order. After getting this I added all the null values. The problem is all the null values are coming good and the actual values are also sorted. But the 1001 comes after 100000001. Please help in solving this. what should i do to meet my requirement?

Comment: Do you actually have `java.lang.Longs` in your list, or are these strings that represent numeric values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 List<Object> list= new ArrayList<>();

    list.add(null);
    list.add("1");
    list.add("2");
    list.add("-2");
    list.add("11fff");
    list.add("22fff");


    Collections.sort(list, (o1, o2) -> {
        if(o1==null) return 1;
        if(o2==null) return -1;

        if(o1.equals(o2)) return 0;

        boolean o1_int = ((String)o1).matches("^-?\\d+$");
        boolean o2_int = ((String)o2).matches("^-?\\d+$");

        if(o1_int && o2_int){
            return Integer.parseInt((String)o1)>Integer.parseInt((String)o2)?1:-1;
        }
        else if(o1_int){
            return -1;
        }else if(o2_int){
            return 1;
        }
        else {
            return ((String) o1).compareTo((String)o2);
        }
    });


    list.forEach(System.out::println);
```

Output is

```
-2
1
2
11fff
22fff
null
```